# Column names missing in Blob as well as Table while running Azure Data Factory (ADF) Pipeline

Tags: azure-table-storage, azure-data-factory, azure-blob-storage

I'm using ADF for storing data from data lake to blob in data flow and copy data from blob to table using copy activity.

This is the data structure in container:

_committed_111 (Block blob)
_started_111 (Block blob)
_SUCCESS (Block blob)
part-00000-1623-1-c000.csv (Block blob)
part-00001-1624-1-c000.csv (Block blob)

I was able to successfully copy data to table storage however column names are missing in both blob as well as table. How do I add it as a part ADF data flow/pipeline?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When headers are missing the problem most of the time is that the dataset you are using to store data un the lake doesnt have the First row as header option checked.

[image: First row as header checked]

If this is already checked, make sure the source is giving the headers properly.

Hope this helped!